# date conversion to timestamp and convert to another date format

Tags: typoscript, typo3-9.x

in the field pi_flexform i have a date formatted like 26.12.2010

with TypoScript i need to convert this date to an RFC-822 format like Wed, 26 Dec 2010

my current code shows like:

```
20 = TEXT
20.wrap = <pubDate>|</pubDate>
20.data = flexform: pi_flexform:settings.datum
20.strtotime = 1
20.strftime = %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:00 +0200
```

but this outputs Mi, 26 Dez 2010

how can i do this only in typoscript?

the date function doesn't work, it return 0

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only direct way to switch to english would be to set the locale of the whole page to english. But I'm guessing that is not an option here. Other ways that come to mind would be a custom viewhelper if you use fluid for your templating (see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/8-Fluid/8-developing-a-custom-viewhelper.html).

But since you want a *pure typoscript* solution the only way I can think of is to put the month / day into the register and run it in a case object. Here is a demo for the month.

If you want the whole date you will have to pierce it together making 4 COAs, first one for the day (CASE), second one for the date, third for the month (CASE) and last for the year:

**BEWARE: this code fragment is an abomination - but it works for this very special scenario :)**

```
lib.test = COA
lib.test {
  wrap = <pubDate>|</pubDate>
  10 = LOAD_REGISTER
  10 {
    month.data = flexform: pi_flexform:settings.datum
    month.strtotime = 1
    month.strftime = %b
    }
  20 = CASE
  20 {
    key = {REGISTER:month}
    key.insertData = 1
    default = TEXT
    default.value = Jan
    Feb = TEXT
    Feb.value = Feb        
    Mrz = TEXT
    Mrz.value = Mar
    Apr = TEXT
    Apr.value = Apr
    Mai = TEXT
    Mai.value = May
    Jun = TEXT
    Jun.value = Jun
    Jul = TEXT
    Jul.value = Jul
    Aug = TEXT
    Aug.value = Aug
    Sep = TEXT
    Sep.value = Sep
    Okt = TEXT
    Okt.value = Oct                
    Nov = TEXT
    Nov.value = Nov
    Dez = TEXT
    Dez.value = Dec
  }
  30 = RESTORE_REGISTER
}
```